High Memory Usage by Chrome based applications- mainly by (video_capture.mojom.VideoCaptureService) component
Within the past few weeks, all Chrome based applications started taking a huge amount of memory on my computer. They keep taking more and more RAM until the system starts getting stuttery. Within the past couple of days (probably after the most recent windows update), I started getting bluescreens. It happened twice in two days.
From the screenshot you can see slack taking up 13 GB, Chrome taking over 7 GB, and Opera taking 2 GB. In every chromium app it is the video_capture.mojom.VideoCaptureService taking up almost all the RAM.
Task Manager Screenshot
Memory usage by Slack processes
If I exit the app, the video_capture process takes around 10 to 15 mins to close. I've seen it stick around for over an hour sometimes. I can't even kill it. It says "Access Denied", even using an Local Admin user.
I'm running Windows 11 24H2 build 26100.2605. I have 128GB RAM with a 32GB page file.
Anything I can do to fix this? Or is a clean re-install the only option?

It seems that one of the November updates to CEF introduced this issue. On my system, Chrome, Edge, and Slack all spawn the video_capture.mojom.VideoCaptureService process, which results in a memory leak (sometimes taking up 60GB). Interestingly, I only noticed this problem after upgrading my laptop's RAM from 32GB to 64GB, as it wasn't as apparent with less available memory.
Unlike your experience, I can terminate the process in Task Manager on my system, which is running Windows 11 (version 23H2, build 22631.3880). This makes me wonder if the difference might be related to how the applications were installed. Perhaps you installed them machine-wide, whereas I installed them per-user.
To work around the issue, I wrote a small PowerShell script to automatically kill the processes and release the memory whenever I login. It is a simple one line command. (Get-CimInstance Win32_Process -Filter "CommandLine LIKE '%video_capture.mojom%'" | Select-Object  ProcessId).ProcessId  | ForEach-Object {Stop-Process -id $_}; You could try to run it with elevated privileges to see if that resolves the issue for you.

Thanks. I'll activate the actual Administrator user, and give that a go. Otherwise I guess I'm stuck until they fix it in an update.

I can kill it using this method, while the application is running. If I exit the application, and the video_capture process is still hanging around, I can't kill it using this method either. But it helps running it to "prune" the processes once in a while.
